# JSF DataModel getRowData always return the first row (which has index zero)

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, richfaces, datamodel

I have rich:select component inside a rich:dataTable  column.
I added a4j:ajax tag to handle onblur event , to process some values related to this selected row.

But this worked only correct for the first row of the datatable , in the second row it do the same as in the first row.

When I traced my code I found that the datamodel.getRowData() method return the first row always.
Also I found that the datamodel.getRowCount() return the correct number of rows.
BUT datamodel.getRowIndex() return ZERO always.

ANY help ???

Here is my ManagedBean code (the needed code only) ****

```
@ManagedBean(name = "saleBacking")
@SessionScoped
public class SaleBacking  implements Serializable{


private DataModel<SaleLine> model ;
   public DataModel<SaleLine> getModel() {
       if (model == null) {
            model = new ListDataModel<SaleLine>(salesLines);
        }
        return model;
    }

  public void updateRowData(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
    {
        currentSaleLine = (SaleLine)getModel().getRowData();
        System.out.println("Row count= "+getModel().getRowCount() + " , Row index= " + getModel().getRowIndex()) ;// this always  return the correct rowCount but the index equal Zero (the first row of the datamodel)
        if(currentSaleLine.getItemId() != null && currentSaleLine != null)
         {
             currentSaleLine.setItemPrice(currentSaleLine.getItemId().getItemDefEndUserPrice());
             currentSaleLine.setPl(currentSaleLine.getItemId().getItemDefEndUserPrice());
             currentSaleLine.setQuantity(1d);
             currentSaleLine.setNetValue(currentSaleLine.getItemPrice() *  currentSaleLine.getQuantity()) ;
             calculateTotalSale();
         }
    }
}
```

**Sale.xhtml**

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{saleBacking.salesLines}" var="line" rows="50" id="datatable">                                  
    <rich:column>
                                               <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.item}" style="font-size:15px;"/></f:facet>
        <rich:select enableManualInput="true" 
                    value="#{line.itemId}"
                    clientFilterFunction="containsFilter"
                    converter="#{itemConverter}"
                    defaultLabel="please write the item name" onlistshow="alert('jhjhj');"
                    >
            <f:selectItems value="#{saleBacking.items}" var="item" itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.code} #{item.name}"/>
            <a4j:ajax event="blur" execute="@this" listener="#{saleBacking.updateRowData}" render="datatable master2"  oncomplete="document.getElementById('myform:datatable:#{line.viewNo-1}:price').focus();"/>
        </rich:select>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: I haven't used this construct before, so I'm not sure. But try `SaleLine currentSaleLine = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{line}", SaleLine.class);` to check if it returns the current row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this construct before, so I'm not sure. But try SaleLine

```
currentSaleLine = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, 
"#{line}", SaleLine.class);
```

To check if it returns the current row.

@BalusC yesterday